# calculate variance of certain columns in a dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I'm trying to calculate the variance of three variables, per row, from a dataframe using `purrr::pmap` and `base::var`.

Reproducible example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

set.seet(123)

df <- data.frame(a = rnorm(10, 100, 5),
                 b = rnorm(10, 100, 5),
                 c = rnorm(10, 100, 5), 
                 d = "abc",
                 e = "cmc")

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(vars_var = pmap(list(a,b,c), ~ var(c(..1, ..2, ..3))))
df
```

Unfortunately this results in all values being `NA`. Could someone point in the right direction

Comment: The example is not perfectly reproducible unless you set the seed before you define `df`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `c` to concatenate to a `vector` and then apply `var`

```
df %>% 
   mutate(vars_var = pmap_dbl(list(a,b,c), ~ var(c(...))))
#            a         b         c   d   e  vars_var
#1  107.99999 103.63304 102.34089 abc cmc  8.794236
#2   95.82441 101.63287  96.35934 abc cmc 10.305745
#3  105.78436  99.18291  99.01016 abc cmc 14.916436
#4   93.40284 103.69875 104.54950 abc cmc 38.496276
#5  109.37737  98.79907 104.43685 abc cmc 28.015604
#6  100.34486  96.36210 101.65905 abc cmc  7.607847
#7   99.64536 105.58825 100.36501 abc cmc 10.519687
#8  100.34628  99.93914 110.02011 abc cmc 32.562415
#9  103.09767 101.59083  96.83285 abc cmc 10.692810
#10 100.27754 102.85691 101.83375 abc cmc  1.686977
```

---

If we use the OP's method, use `unlist` after concatenating as it is still a `list`

```
df %>%
   mutate(vars_var = pmap(list(a, b, c), ~ var(unlist(c(..1, ..2, ..3)))))
```

Comment: @adl Can you show the version of `purrr/dplyr`.  I used `packageVersion('purrr')
[1] ‘0.2.5'`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will accept it as soon as possible. Strangely the notation: `..1`, `..2`, `..3` didn't work, but it should be the same thing as the `c(...)`. Do you know why ?

Comment: @adl  The reason is that you are applying the `var` to a `list` and it won't work `var(list(1, 3, 4))`

Answer (score 1):

Or move 100% to  base `R`:

```
apply(df[c("a", "b", "c")], 1, var)
```